# TF Dataset from Keras Sequence Class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I thought I would share something that took me a while to figure out: easily wrapping an existing Keras Sequence Class with a TF Dataset object. After following tutorials and migrating from TF 1.X and Keras to TF 2.X I finally figured out how to do it with minimal code. Hopefully I'm not the only one who struggled with this and others will find this helpful :)

A few assumptions:

- Sequence class loads data and labels
- Labels have the same shape (apart from channels) as the source data (i.e. this is something I use for training U-Nets)
- Data format is channels last

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def DatasetFromSequenceClass(sequenceClass, stepsPerEpoch, nEpochs, batchSize, dims=[512,512,3], n_classes=2, data_type=tf.float32, label_type=tf.float32):
    # eager execution wrapper
    def DatasetFromSequenceClassEagerContext(func):
        def DatasetFromSequenceClassEagerContextWrapper(batchIndexTensor):
            # Use a tf.py_function to prevent auto-graph from compiling the method
            tensors = tf.py_function(
                func,
                inp=[batchIndexTensor],
                Tout=[data_type, label_type]
            )

            # set the shape of the tensors - assuming channels last
            tensors[0].set_shape([batchSize, dims[0], dims[1], dims[2]])   # [samples, height, width, nChannels]
            tensors[1].set_shape([batchSize, dims[0], dims[1], n_classes]) # [samples, height, width, nClasses for one hot]
            return tensors
        return DatasetFromSequenceClassEagerContextWrapper

    # TF dataset wrapper that indexes our sequence class
    @DatasetFromSequenceClassEagerContext
    def LoadBatchFromSequenceClass(batchIndexTensor):
        # get our index as numpy value - we can use .numpy() because we have wrapped our function
        batchIndex = batchIndexTensor.numpy()

        # zero-based index for what batch of data to load; i.e. goes to 0 at stepsPerEpoch and starts cound over
        zeroBatch = batchIndex % stepsPerEpoch

        # load data
        data, labels = sequenceClass[zeroBatch]

        # convert to tensors and return
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(data), tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)

    # create our data set for how many total steps of training we have
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(stepsPerEpoch*nEpochs)

    # return dataset using map to load our batches of data, use TF to specify number of parallel calls
    return dataset.map(LoadBatchFromSequenceClass, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

With that function, you can then update your training to look something like this:

```py
# load our data as tensorflow datasets
training = DatasetFromSequenceClass(trainingSequence, training_steps, nEpochs, batchSize, dims=shp, n_classes=nClasses)
validation = DatasetFromSequenceClass(validationSequence, validation_steps, nEpochs, batchSize, dims=shp, n_classes=nClasses)

# train
model_object.fit(training,
    steps_per_epoch=training_steps,
    validation_data=validation,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    epochs=nEpochs,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose=1)
```

From here there are lots of other options for the Dataset API (like prefetch), but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: This is great, but I have a follow-up: What if we want to return multiple tensors as part of `data`? If `tensors` has more than 2 elements, Tensorflow complains: ```ValueError: Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`, or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(512, 128) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(512, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(512, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>)```